# No Sound: ALSA states no soundcards found (NVIDIA HDMI/Displayport)

Tags: nvidia, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, displayport

I ran `alsa-info` through terminal and the output is:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d5aa5cc8737c0b9f3613d45cbfb475c5b9245f3b

Alsa seems to find my PCI card, but it doesn't seem to want to use my Audio controller. It worked before, but now it stopped working.

Any ideas would be appreciated.